# Weird behaviour of Java iterators

Tags: java, iterator, iterable

I've encounter a weird problem when using Java iterators.

In a certain function a receive an iterable object called `filelist`, and I perform the following :

```
System.out.println("First iteration:");
for(Text t : filelist) System.out.println(t);
System.out.println("Second iteration:");
for(Text t : filelist) System.out.println(t);
```

and the output is:

```
First iteration:

file2.txt

file1.txt

file1.txt

Second iteration:
```

`filelist` is of type `Iterable<Text>`. I'm working with the Hadoop map/reduce framework.

So my question is, why is file list empty in the second loop, when I didn't change it in the first one?

Comment: What is the type of `filelist`?

Comment: Iterable<Text>. I'm working with the hadoop map/reduce framework.

Comment: This code is used in a reducer class, so since i'm using the hadoop framework, i presume that each reducer receives a List<Text> object. right ?

Comment: List is also an interface. Add `System.out.println(filelist.getClass().getName());`, and tell what you get. That said, whatever the type is, unless the underlyng data structure is modified concurrently, this should never happen.

Comment: The returned value is : org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.ReduceContextImpl$ValueIterable

Comment: Please don't add an answer into your question.  If the answer below addressed your problem, you should accept it instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Iterable` might return the `iterator` that might be non-reiterable. Nothing in it's interface says it can't. So in your case it seems that `Iterable` is designed by library authors to be only used once. If you want to iterate second time, you need to store values in your own structure. I.e. you can first do

```
List<Text> myList = new ArrayList(filelist)
```

Comment: You mean the Iterable, not the Iterator. An Iterator is never reiterable. It's true that the Iterable doc doesn't mention anything, but I've never seen any Iterable that can only be iterated once. It should be an Iterator or a Stream rather than an Iterable.

Comment: Still `Iterable` just returns iterator. So, I've meant, that interface doesn't enforce `Iterable` to have every call to `iterator()` return new and ready instance. Iterable just `allows an object to be the target of the "foreach" statement`